# Wordpress get terms by their order in certain post

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

in my website am fetching the terms with this method

```php
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($article_id, 'category_article', [
    'number' => 3
]);
```

Am trying to get terms by their order in that specific post
for example: in this post the terms are - (orange,apple)
in other post its (apple,orange).

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code -

```
echo strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'job_titles', '', ', ') );
//'job_titles' Replace with your taxonomy slug
```

Might it can help you.

Comment: Thank you for trying, but i think you didn't get the question.
still getting the same order